# jQuery Ajax request with params to an url containing an underscore

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox

I was trying to make a regular GET Ajax call to a Url like `http://localhost:3000/foo_bar`. The call would be something like `$.ajax({url: "/foo_bar", data: { my: "params" }})`. The strange thing is that this would work fine in Chrome. But as soon as I started to test this in FF, I would get an error. The Ajax call was never completed - instead, the request failed somewhere deep down in the jQuery framework. If I removed the data parameter, it would work fine, though. It took me ages to figure out that the problem was the underscore in 'foo_bar'. When I changed that to a hyphen, the request completed as expected in both browsers. Does anyone know why this is? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

generally, I think the underscore is treated as word joiner rather than a separator
So '/foo_bar' is just '/foobar'. Don't know whether that is the problem.